# How Can I create a wrapper module in Angular2 for multiple modules?

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to clean up my project structure and I wanted to keep my AppComponent as clean as possible. I am importing angular2 material in its own file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Material
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular2-material/input';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdListModule } from '@angular2-material/list';
import { MdIconModule, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';

export const MATERIAL_UI_MODULES = [
  MdCardModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdListModule
]
export const MATERIAL_UI_REGISTRIES = [
  MdIconRegistry
]
```

and inside my AppController I am using it as follows:

```
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  ...MATERIAL_UI_REGISTRIES
];

const APP_MODULES = [
    ...MATERIAL_UI_MODULES,
];

@NgModule({
  imports:APP_MODULES,
  declarations: APP_DECLARATIONS,
  bootstrap:[AppComponent],
  providers: APP_PROVIDERS,
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

but is there a way to create a `MaterialModule` that I can just import and not have to worry about adding individual modules or providers.

I have tried creating a MaterialModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    ...MATERIAL_UI_MODULES,
  ],
  providers: MATERIAL_UI_REGISTRIES,
})
export class MaterialModule {

}
```

and importing in my AppComponent:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    //...MATERIAL_UI_MODULES,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: APP_DECLARATIONS,
  bootstrap:[AppComponent],
  providers: APP_PROVIDERS,
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

But I get the following error

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-card-title' is a Web Component then add    "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to 
suppress this message. ("....
```

Comment: have you tried creating MaterialModule before asking?

Comment: @micronyks I have but I get an error (I have updated the Question to include this)

Comment: You know anything about `sharedModule` ?

Comment: @micronyks Not specifically but after googling it, is that not what I am doing?

Comment: SharedModule will resolve your problem. check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Comment: @micronyks sorry still a little confused, am I right in saying I need to import all the components from each of the material modules and add to my shared module exports ?

Comment: @micronyks I just figured it out, Thank you... If you wanted to add an answer I would be happy to accept, If not I can just answer. Thank you

Comment: That's great to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SharedModule**. Declare common things in **SharedModule** and then import **SharedModule** in components where you want to use common things.

Learn more about SharedModule here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module